# Calculate Normal Vector on Fitted Surface

Tags: matlab, vector, surface

Is there any straight way to derive a normal vector on a linear surface fitted to data.
The surface is created by `fit` function on my X,Y,Z data points:

```
sf = fit([X2, Y2],Z2,'poly11');
c = coeffvalues(sf);
P0 = [0; 0; c(1)];
plot(sf,[X2,Y2],Z2)
```

The linear polynomial surface in the graph:
[image]
Now I need to get the normal `N` vector in order to calculate the distances from all point to the surface by dot function:

```
dot(sf-P0,N)
```

Any guidance?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, according to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472153/normal-vector-to-plane) and many other sources, if you define a plane in the form of

`Ax + By + Cz = D`

Then, the normal vector you are looking for would be [A, B, C].

Now by using fit, you obtain a sf object, whos coeffvalues c are in such an order that

`z=c(1)+c(2)x+c(3)y`

which is the same as

`c(2)x+c(3)y-z=c(1)`

There, you get a normal vector, **N=[c(2), c(3), -1]**.

Then, to calculate the distance between P0 and the surface, [one way](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html) is

`(P0 * (N.') + c(1)) / norm(N)`

Comment: @X Zhang: thanks, let me check